# RDFLIB does not set xml:base entry

Tags: python, xml, rdflib

I'm reading with RDFLIB an OWL file in RDF/XML format by using parse method that has an xml:base field set. Now, if I use the rdflib serialize method with parameter format='xml', the xml:base field is totally missing from the output ontology. I have also used the parameter 'base' with the serialize method, the method bind, but nothing seems to set the xml:base entry. There is any way to set the xml:base field of an ontology?. Many thanks.

Comment: Please show your code and the xml part.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread on rdflib issues](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/issues/248)  mentions that

> ...the base URI shouldn't contain a **hash**...

as the reason why the `base=` argument of `Graph.serialize()` has no effect.

As a workaround, I can suggest using empty prefix with `bind` method:

```py
    g.bind('', "http://my.namespace/my-onto#")
    g.serialize(destination='out.xml')  # no `base=` here
```

The result is the default namespace (and probably a smaller overall file):

```xml
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns="http://my.namespace/my-onto#"
  <!-- ... -->
>
<!-- ... -->
</rdf:RDF>
```